# JPQL IS NOT NULL is returning objects with NULL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpql

I have the following `JPQL` query:

```
@Query("select p FROM Partner p where p.partnerIdentifier IS NOT NULL")
    List<Partner> findAfterDates();
```

This should return all `Partner Entities` that `DO NOT` have NULL for `partnerIdentifier`.

However, I am running the code and debugging, and I am seeing that the returned `Collection` contains `entities` that has `null` for this field.

Is this a bug in `JPQL`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A colleague came by and suggested I use a `join` since the `inner` object was a `one to one` mapped object.

The following now returns correct results:

```
@Query("select p FROM Partner p join p.partnerIdentifier pi where pi is not null")
List<Partner> findAfterDates();
```

Once again a reminder that underneath hibernate we have a `relational database` and that something that logically should work using `oop`/`jpql` doesn't.

Comment: In case You want to use IS NULL remember to use LEFT JOIN.