JPA query does not fetch not null records
I am trying to fetch data from a large table.
I am using jpa named query to fetch using pageable parameter.
In the result there are some rows which has NULL values.
So I am trying to fetch NOT NULL columns using jpa query and DTO projections.
But the query returns the records with NULL values.
Here is my query:
@Repository
public interface ListElementRepository extends JpaRepository<ListElement,Integer> {
    @Query("""
        SELECT new com.mavenir.cms.ext.dto.ListElementDto(l.id,l.name,l.fkDataModel,l.metadata,l.hasPassword) 
        from ListElement l
        where l.hasPassword=:hasPassword and l.fkDataModel is not null and l.metadata is not null
    """)
    Page<ListElementDto> findByHasPassword(String hasPassword, Pageable pageable);
}

Result:

I used findByHasPasswordAndFkDataModelIsNotNull and this is returning non null records.
I don't understand why the named query is not working.
Here is my Entity class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "yang_list")
public class ListElement {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String yangSchema;
    private String scopeType;
    private String visibility;
    private Integer sequence;
    private Integer fkDataModel;
    private Integer fkModule;
    private String moduleName;
    private String confdPath;
    private String nodeType;
    private List<String> columns;
    private String rebootAttributes;
    private String metadata;
    private String keyLeaf;

    private String isAugmentedNode;
    private String augmentedNamespace;
    private String augTargetPath;
    private String augTargetModuleNs;
    private String isLiTableEnabled;

    private String hasPassword;

    public ListElement() {
    }

    public ListElement(String name, String scopeType, String moduleName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.scopeType = scopeType;
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "yang_schema", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getYangSchema() {
        return yangSchema;
    }

    public void setYangSchema(String yangSchema) {
        this.yangSchema = yangSchema;
    }

    @Column(name = "scope_type", nullable = false)
    public String getScopeType() {
        return scopeType;
    }

    public void setScopeType(String scopeType) {
        this.scopeType = scopeType;
    }

    @Column(name = "visibility", nullable = false)
    public String getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(String visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }

    @Column(name = "sequence", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    public Integer getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

    public void setSequence(Integer sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    @Column(name = "fk_yang_module")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Integer getFkModule() {
        return fkModule;
    }

    public void setFkModule(Integer fkModule) {
        this.fkModule = fkModule;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getModuleName() {
        return moduleName;
    }

    public void setModuleName(String moduleName) {
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
    }

    @Column(name = "confd_path")
    public String getConfdPath() {
        return confdPath;
    }

    public void setConfdPath(String confdPath) {
        this.confdPath = confdPath;
    }
    @Column(name = "node_type")
    public String getNodeType() {
        return nodeType;
    }

    public void setNodeType(String nodeType) {
        this.nodeType = nodeType;
    }

    @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "columns", length = 1000)
    public List<String> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(List<String> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    @Column(name = "reboot_attributes")
    public String getRebootAttributes() {
        return rebootAttributes;
    }

    public void setRebootAttributes(String rebootAttributes) {
        this.rebootAttributes = rebootAttributes;
    }
    @Column(name = "yang_metadata")
    public String getMetadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    public void setMetadata(String metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }
    @Column(name = "fk_data_module")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Integer getFkDataModel() {
        return fkDataModel;
    }

    public void setFkDataModel(Integer fkDataModel) {
        this.fkDataModel = fkDataModel;
    }

    @Column(name = "key_leaf")
    public String getKeyLeaf() {
        return keyLeaf;
    }

    public void setKeyLeaf(String keyLeaf) {
        this.keyLeaf = keyLeaf;
    }

    @Column(name = "is_augmented_node")
    public String getIsAugmentedNode() {
        return isAugmentedNode;
    }

    public void setIsAugmentedNode(String isAugmentedNode) {
        this.isAugmentedNode = isAugmentedNode;
    }

    @Column(name = "augmented_namespace")
    public String getAugmentedNamespace() {
        return augmentedNamespace;
    }

    public void setAugmentedNamespace(String augmentedNamespace) {
        this.augmentedNamespace = augmentedNamespace;
    }

    @Column(name = "aug_target_path")
    public String getAugTargetPath() {
        return augTargetPath;
    }

    public void setAugTargetPath(String augTargetPath) {
        this.augTargetPath = augTargetPath;
    }

    @Column(name = "aug_target_ns")
    public String getAugTargetModuleNs() {
        return augTargetModuleNs;
    }

    public void setAugTargetModuleNs(String augTargetModuleNs) {
        this.augTargetModuleNs = augTargetModuleNs;
    }


    @Column(name = "is_li_table_enabled", nullable = false)
    public String getIsLiTableEnabled() {
        return isLiTableEnabled;
    }

    public void setIsLiTableEnabled(String isLiTableEnabled) {
        this.isLiTableEnabled = isLiTableEnabled;
    }

    public JSONObject returnMetaData(String prefix,Integer cId,Boolean 
    @Column(name = "has_password")
    public String getHasPassword() {
        return hasPassword;
    }

    public void setHasPassword(String hasPassword) {
        this.hasPassword = hasPassword;
    }
}

My DTO is:
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class ListElementDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer fkDataModel;
    private String metadata;
    private String hasPassword;
}


Can you show an example of the result?

attached the result

If you don't want null values return you can use Jackson ... it's just a matter of serialization / deserialization ... just add this to your dtos classes
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyDto { ... }
You should have a look here : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields

@davidvera I don't think it's a matter of serialization, but more of "why does the query returns null values when I explicitly discarded them in the WHERE clause"

Sorry, I misread the question... if you have issue with your query:
Use the named queries: for instance it should be like this :
findByHasPasswordAndFkDataModelIsNotNull()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945898/is-not-null-always-return-true-jpa-query

@manjosh are fkDataModel and metadata maybe related entities?
This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247896/jpql-is-not-null-is-returning-objects-with-null question seems to be the same as yours, and the problem was that the OP was trying to use IS NOT NULL on related entities (which won't work the same as we would expect a relational db to work)

@pochopsp, they are not related entities, fkDataModel is an integer and metadata is a string

Try please to inner/left join the table itself. It should remove nulls and work with your condition.
FROM ListElement l
INNER JOIN ListElement l2 ON l.id = l2.id

Please add your entities and dto to the question.
